# Trying to catch a FormatException error fails. Only Exception can catch it?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, error-handling

I have a method that accepts random data at runtime (it could be `string`, `int`, etc.) and then it tries adding this data to a list of a random type (e.g. `List<byte>`, `List<int>`, etc.).

Due to the unpredictable nature of this, I have added 2 error handling routines.  One to catch a `FormatException` error and do some specific actions to fix the data.  And secondly, I've also added a general catch-all for `Exception` so if another error I'm not expecting is thrown, I can display the details and exit the application gracefully.

The weird issue I'm having (or at least it seems weird to me), is that whenever a `FormatException` error is thrown, my `Catch (FormatException ex)` does nothing and instead the error is being caught by `Catch (Exception ex)`.  So rather than being able to handle the error properly, the application exits instead.

To help isolate this, I've created a small example C# WinForms program that replicates the issue.

Here's the main form code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This works normally        
    ErrorClass.TestCatchFormatException<string, string>("abc", "def");

    // This also works normally        
    ErrorClass.TestCatchFormatException<int, int>("123", "456");

    // This should raise a FormatException error but only Exception catches it???
    ErrorClass.TestCatchFormatException<int, string>("abc", "456"); 
}
```

And here's the code for my 2 classes:

```
public class DataClass<T, U>
{
    public T Data1 { get; set; }
    public U Data2 { get; set; }
}

public static class ErrorClass
{
    public static void TestCatchFormatException<T, U>(dynamic inputString, dynamic inputString2)
        where T : IComparable<T>
        where U : IComparable<U>
    {
        try
        {
            List<DataClass<T, U>> theList = new List<DataClass<T, U>>();
            TypeConverter converter1 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            TypeConverter converter2 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(U));

            theList.Add(new DataClass<T, U>
            {
                Data1 = converter1.ConvertFrom(inputString.ToString()),
                Data2 = converter2.ConvertFrom(inputString2.ToString())
            });

            MessageBox.Show(
                "Data1 Value is: " + theList[0].Data1.ToString() + "\n"
                + "Data1 Type is: " + theList[0].Data1.GetType().ToString() + "\n"
                + "Data2 Value is: " + theList[0].Data2.ToString() + "\n"
                + "Data2 Type is: " + theList[0].Data2.GetType().ToString());
        }

        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            // Catches nothing for some reason               
            MessageBox.Show("Caught FormatException\n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.InnerException);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // This catches the error but InnerException says the error is of type FormatException.  
            // Yet FormatException doesn't catch it???
            MessageBox.Show("Caught Exception\n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
}
```

Even weirder is that when I look at the InnerException the catch-all `Exception` generates, it says this:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

So it is detecting it as a `FormatException` error.  Yet for some reason, catching `FormatException` does nothing and only `Exception` can catch it.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this C# 6.0 btw? If so you can use: `catch (Exception ex) when (ex.InnerException is FormatException)`

Comment: Sadly I'm still on C# 5.0.  Although you've just given me a very good reason to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/basenumberconverter.cs,b18b536898233ffd) internally calls a helper function to throw an exception:

```
public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
     ...
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw FromStringError(text, e);
        }
    }
    return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
}
```

The implementation of `FromStringError` is:

```
internal virtual Exception FromStringError(string failedText, Exception innerException) {
        return new Exception(SR.GetString(SR.ConvertInvalidPrimitive, failedText, TargetType.Name), innerException);
}
```

So it throws an `Exception` that wraps the actual `FormatException` and adds some additional information (namely the value it's trying to convert and the type it's trying to convert to).  Why it doesn't throw another `FormatException` I don't know.

Prior to C# 6 there was no way to create a `catch` that would catch based on the `InnerException`.  You'd have to catch `Exception` and inspect the `InnerException` type to handle it differently.

With C# 6 you can use an exception filter:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex.InnerExcpetion is FormatException)
{
    // Catches nothing for some reason               
    MessageBox.Show("Caught FormatException\n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.InnerException);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    // This catches the error but InnerException says the error is of type FormatException.  
    // Yet FormatException doesn't catch it???
    MessageBox.Show("Caught Exception\n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense now.  I still don't understand why they made it throw a general Exception instead of re-throwing the FormatException.  But this explains it and as I'm not on C# 6.0 yet, I used If (ex.InnerException.ToString().StartsWith("System.FormatException")) to catch it instead.

Comment: A safer method would be `if(ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException is FormatException)` but it sounds like you get the basic idea.

Comment: Good point.  I hadn't thought of checking for null because I was only expecting errors with an InnerException.  But you're right, this could be an issue so I've updated my code with a null check.  Thanks for the updated suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Your `FormatException` is being wrapped in some other `Exception` type.  That's why the **.InnerException** property has a `FormatException`.  Try calling **.GetType** on the exception you are getting to see the wrapping type, and catch that instead.

Comment: Makes the most sense. I'm able to catch `FormatException` in a sample console app without any problems. My guess would also be a wrapper `Exception` is being thrown.

Comment: Nice idea.  However it just returned type of System.Exception so it doesn't look like there is any other way to catch it.